# Use RAM disk on AWS Codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am trying to speed up the build in AWS codebuild. I would like to use the RAM disk on AWS Codebuild.

I am using the ubuntu environment image.

I tried the methods described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152868/how-do-i-make-a-ram-disk) but didn't work.

```
[Container] 2022/08/25 10:35:01 Running command sudo mkdir -p /media/ramdisk

[Container] 2022/08/25 10:35:02 Running command sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=512M tmpfs /media/ramdisk
mount: /media/ramdisk: permission denied.

[Container] 2022/08/25 10:35:02 Command did not exit successfully sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=512M tmpfs /media/ramdisk exit status 32
[Container] 2022/08/25 10:35:02 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2022/08/25 10:35:02 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=512M tmpfs /media/ramdisk. Reason: exit status 32
```

Comment: "didn't work." is not specific. What exactly is happening? What is your buildspec.yml? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Marcin added the error message and the issue was due to the privileged set to false.

Answer (score 0):

changing privileged to true in Environment settings resolved the issue.